# How to save and reuse Scala utility code

Tags: scala

What is a nice approach for collecting and using useful Scala utility functions across projects. The focus here on really simple, standalone functions like:

```
def toBinary(i: Int, digits: Int = 8) =
    String.format("%" + digits + "s", i.toBinaryString).replace(' ', '0')

def concat(ss: String*) = ss filter (_.nonEmpty) mkString ", "
concat: (ss: String*)String
```

This question is basic, I know ;-) but, I've learned that there is always an optimum way to do something. For example, reusing code from within the Scala interactive shell, Idea, Eclipse, with or without SBT, having the library hosed on GitHub, ect, could quickly introduce optimal, and non-optimal approaches to such a simple problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might want to put such methods in a [package object](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html#).

You could also put them in a normal `object` and import everything in the object when you need those methods.

```
object Utilities {
  def toBinary(i: Int, digits: Int = 8) = // ...
}

// Import everything in the Utilities object
import Utilities._
```

Comment: Thanks. To this point I actually did put my utility functions in an object. I just wanted the assurance that this was a good way, and if I was not incurring any penalties (performance flexibility or other) by using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it trivially accessible from everywhere, your best bet is actually to stick it inside the scala-library jar.  Personally, I have all my custom stuff in `/jvm/S.jar` (or something like that) and add it to the classpath every time I need it.

Repacking the Scala library jar is really easy--unpack it, move your class hierarchy in, and pack it up again.  (You should have it inside some package and/or package object.)

Comment: Ok, you could do that but I don't think it is a good idea to put it in the Scala library JAR. You're then essentially making your own extended version of Scala. You'll easily forget which methods aren't part of standard Scala and your program isn't going to work on other people's computers which don't have a patched version of the Scala library JAR.

Comment: @Jesper - It's not quite _that_ bad; you still have to import your own package or object.  It's just a handy way to avoid having to fix a half dozen different tools so that they use the right classpath.  (I typically fix the tools, but still....)

Comment: Thanks Rex. That's an interesting approach. How does the result of this compare to the publish-local command in SBT? I'm still learning, but I suppose if I use it via SBT, then it will not be typically accessible via the Scala interactive shell? Is it ok to use the approach of putting everything in an object, or is that a bit of a hack?

Comment: @JacobusR - Putting everything in an object is typical (see Jesper's answer).  I don't really use SBT, so I'm not sure what publish-local does beyond SBT itself, if anything.